# 2 Ubuntu in booting options and windows8 how to remove one?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, delete

How to clean the booting options of my laptop since i am seeing windows 8, ubuntu volume 2 and another ubuntu volume 2 (that doesn't exist) since i made a new installation of the OS again? I don't want to remove the both operating systems, what i want is to get rid of the other options of ubuntu on the list (there is nothing in there when you click it says : insert disk or press enter to choose blah blah..)

Answer (score 0):

For a recent version of Ubuntu, you need to edit the grub2 menu files.  See the link to "Grub2 Revisited" in the response to question:

[How can I edit my Grub bootloader entries (Hide, Rename, Remove)? Preferably doing it manually, and not with a program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi/81778#81778)

The blog posting has a detailed set of instructions.