# The partitions can't be merged because they don't see each other

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, gparted, merge

I have the following

[image]

where `/dev/sda2` -  Windows7 and "`unallocated`" is the partition I want to add to my current Linux installation at `/dev/sda6`. But I can't do this for some reason. Even when I format unallocated partition and then I click Resize, I can only make it smaller. The same thing is true for `/dev/sda6`.

In other words, `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda6` don't see each other.

So how can I merge `/dev/sda1` into `/dev/sda6`?

There is no much menu item "resize" on /dev/sda3, although it's not mounted:

```
a@a ~ $ sudo umount /dev/sda3
umount: /dev/sda3: not mounted
a@a ~ $ sudo umount /dev/sda6
umount: /dev/sda6: not mounted
a@a ~ $ sudo umount /dev/sda5
umount: /dev/sda5: not mounted
```

UPDATE2:

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0 829.8G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0  98.2G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1  14.6G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.5G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   1.1G  1 loop /rofs
```

[image]

Clicking on /dev/sda3 and choosing "resize"
[image]

Comment: Alex you would also like this: [How can I edit my Grub bootloader entries (Hide, Rename, Remove)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge 718 GB unallocated space with the `/dev/sda6`, you have to follow the below steps.

1. First boot from Ubuntu live disk and mark sure that all the partitions are unmounted.Gparted won't resize a mounted partition.
2. Now right-click on the `/dev/sda2` partition and click on resize.Move the dragger to the extreme left, so that the unallocated space will come just below to the `/dev/sda2` partition.
3. Right-click on the extended partition (`/dev/sda3`) and select Resize option.Now you can be able to add the unallocated space to your extended partition.
4. Now the Unallocated space will comes inside your extended partition ie, just below to the `/dev/sda5` partition.
5. Right-click on the `/dev/sda5` partition, select Resize option and move the dragger to extreme right.So that the unallocated space will come just above to the `/dev/sda5` partition.
6. Now you can be able to resize your `/dev/sda6` Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Also see this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/389067/202806), it would help you for resizing the partitions.

Comment: But there is no menu "resize" when I'm clicking on /dev/sda3 for some reason, it's disabled.

Comment: I already told, boot from Ubuntu live disk and unmount all the partitions.In your screenshot it seems like your extended partition is mounted.Please unmount that.

Comment: I booted from live cd! Screen wasn't made from live cd.

Comment: Unmount all the partitions before doing any operations.

Comment: How can I unmount them? In "folder manager" they look unmounted.

Comment: See you gparted screenshot. In that your /dev/sda3,sda6 and sda5 partitions are mounted.Key symbol means that the partition is mounted.

Comment: look at my update.

Comment: post the gparted screenshot.

Comment: I'm asking again: How can I unmount them and make sure I've done it?

Comment: It would be better, if you upload the new gparted screenshot.And also post the output of `lsblk` command.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Your sda5 partition is mounted.Try to unmount it by running `sudo umount /dev/sda5`

Comment: `umount: /dev/sda5: not mounted`

Comment: sorry, you need to swapoff that partition.Right click on the swap partition and select swapoff.That's all. :-)

Comment: there is no space to add to /dev/sda3 now, look at my update please.

Comment: Why you add that unallocated space with your ntfs partition?It's ok, now resize your /dev/sda2 ntfs partition and shrink it's space to get out the desired size.

Comment: I did. shouldn't I add that unallocated space to /dev/sda6 instead of /dev/sda3?

Comment: We can talk here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Comment: sorry, I can't login there for some reason. Can you post the answer here?

Comment: I got it, I should add it to sda3 frist, then to sda6.

Comment: first you have to add the space to your extended partition.

Comment: yes, yes your'e correct.If it was under the sda5 partition, then follow my answer.Or if it is above the /dev/sda6 partition then you can directly resize it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep both Windows and Ubuntu, but give Ubuntu some more space on sda6? First of all BACK UP IMPORTANT DATA! Things can go wrong (although they shouldn't, you can never be too safe!) The issue here is that:

a -  It appears that you are booted up onto that specific hard drive at the moment. You cannot modify partitions when you are currently using that drive. To remedy this, boot into a live USB (using your Ubuntu Install disk).

b - When you want to merge two partitions, you need to have them side by side. To do this you need to

1 select sda2, and move it to the left (using the partition menu>move).
Note: There will be an error that pops up, warning you about failure to boot, this is normal!

[image: Step 1]

2 Select sda3, click resize, and add the unallocated space to sda3 by dragging the slider on the left all the way to the left. It should look somewhat like this:

[image: Step 2]

3 Select sda6, click resize, and add the unallocated space to sda6.

[image: Step 3]

Afterwards, your diagram should look somewhat like this:

[image: Final Product]

Now what you want to do is click the green checkbox to apply the changes. This will take a long time!

WARNING: after this is done, your computer may not boot up! To remedy this, you have to re-install grub (the screen that you see before you boot into windows or ubuntu). There are two ways to do this:

Either way, you need a Live CD/USB stick to boot off of. I found pretty detailed instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/). The first method is easier (but you need to have a live CD of ubuntu 12.04 or later, and have internet access), but the second method (via terminal) works too. Just follow the instructions, and feel free to ask any questions!

Here to help,

Dev Newb

note: The pictures will vary slightly from yours (the partition sizes/labels etc), but the overall method should work. Also, I am using gparted on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but it should work the same on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: It won't work.`/dev/sda6` is in extended partition.See my answer.

Comment: It should work! I have done it. the drive numbers in the screenshot differ from the original, but the order of the partitions is the same. (btw, sda6 is ext4)

Comment: In some cases, the unallocated space will be on the top or at the bottom of the extended partition after resizing it.If it's on the top, your answer will work.But if it's on the bottom, then?

Comment: Yes, but if he follows my instructions, it should stay still work properly. I have done this myself. He simply needs to resize the extended partition NOT move it.

Comment: how can I unmount the partitions? I looks like /dev/sda3 is mounted even I'm on live cd now and thus I can't add resize it.

Comment: In gparted, right click the partition and select unmount. (You will have to unmount sda5 and sda6 before you can unmount sda3)

Comment: but still there is no such the enabled menu item in there.

Comment: In gparted, all the mounted partitions have a  small symbol by them. In your screenshot, for example,  sda3,5, and 6 are mounted

Comment: You are sure they are not mounted?

Comment: Make sure you have selected the correct partition, click the partition and click 'Resize/Move.' Is this grated out? If so, could you upload a screenshot?

Comment: edit: sorry! do NOT delete the windows partition!!

Comment: Here is what you need to do: resize the windows partition and move the slider on the right so you have some free space on the right of the windows partition. From there, you can add the free space to the extended partition etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not merge partition. Unallocated partition is without file system and must be formatted before usage. Your /dev/sda6 is logical partition on primary partition /dev/sda3 and can not be bigger then host partition /dev/sda3 without space for /dev/sda5.

Solution is to move partition /dev/sda2 on beginning of disk. After that to move and resize  partition /dev/sda3 to max space. And at the end resize logical partition /dev/sda6.

I'm not sure, maybe work.

Best of all is to backup data and do fresh install of booth system.