# How to make grub2 recognize other Ubuntu installations again?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Until 13.10 and the `grub2` version used there (version number is 2.02~beta2-... since years/multiple Ubuntu releases) parallel Ubuntu installations on other partitions (both with and without separate boot partitions, both with EFI and legacy BIOS) where recognized and available for multiboot. This is no longer the case. What is the criteria to make `update-grub`/`grub-probe -t device /boot/grub` recognize partitions again?

My current setup is having an EFI System Partition (ESF) with `boot` and `esf` flag set and different `/boot/` partitions (`ext4`) and different OS/root partitions (`ext4` and `btrfs` with Linux different derivates (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora) installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `parted` and GParted, an ESP is identified by a "boot flag," but there's no such thing as an "esf flag" in either program. Thus, it's unclear to me what you mean by that. Please check it and report the actual "flags" set. It's unlikely that this detail is directly related to your problem, but it might be.

AFAIK, current versions of GRUB should recognize older Ubuntu installations. If yours is not doing so, you should consider [filing a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) A post here does *not* qualify, since it will be sheer chance if the right Ubuntu developer sees a post here.

One possible legitimate reason that auto-detection might not be working is that your older installations might be missing or damaged. You should post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file generated by [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (installable as `boot-info-script` in Ubuntu) so that others can examine your configuration for evidence that this is or is not the case.

Two alternatives occur to me if you're having problems with auto-detection of OSes that are actually present:

- You can [manually edit your GRUB configuration file.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi) You'll need to know enough about your other installations to identify them to GRUB.
- You can use [another EFI boot loader for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) Most of these will require manual configuration, but my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) may be able to pick up your other installations with little or no configuration.