# How to install Linux Mint if I have deleted Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I used to have a dual-boot system consisting of Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. Now I have deleted the partition for Ubuntu but the GRUB loader is still there, only that it has more limited commands now. Can I install Linux Mint using the GRUB from the uninstalled Ubuntu or do I have to remove GRUB completely and then install Linux Mint?

Answer (score 1):

GRUB is just a bootloader, it should not have any impact on what you can install and what not.

Chances are that there are still some valid boot-configurations lying around, which is why they show up in the menu though you deleted the Ubuntu-partition (you probably did not delete the bootsector, thus they are still there).

When you install Linux Mint it should override your installation of GRUB, thus you will have a fresh GRUB.

If you want to get rid of the remaining ubuntu-bootsectors, [check out this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi)

Answer (score 1):

No , you don't need to do anything extra, just create a bootable pendrive of linux mint and you can install. but this time option `Alongside windows boot manager` option won't show up. You will have to select Do `something else option` and then identify your old ext4 partitions ,format them and give a single partition for / directory i.e root ( no swap needed for newer system , you can do few extra partition for boot and home ,but not necessary), and you are done ! Old grub is overridden by newer grub :) grub menu back .