# Uninstall Kali Linux from triple boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uninstall, kali

I have Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04 and Kali installed. The grub is of Ubuntu. I would like to remove Kali but I have no idea as to how to do it. Can someone help me ?

Comment: how did you installed them?? can you please provide your disk- screenshot so i can understand in which partitions you have installed kali.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Backup your data
2. Boot into Ubuntu
3. Delete the Kali partition(s), using GParted or other partitioning software
4. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Paraphrased from here: [Remove OS from Linux Dual-Boot - Super User](https://superuser.com/a/227552/443564)

Answer (score 0):

It so much easy.Just format the partition in which you have installed Kali Linux and remove entry for Kali Linux from bootloader

for formating partition you can use `Disks` software which you will find in accessory.I personally don't suggest you to use that app, instead you can use Gparted which you can install by `sudo apt install gparted`

suppose my kali linux is installed in tesing partion.Then I will format that partition to ext4 but if you want that partion to be detected in windows , you should use NTFS.
[image]

after this ,Apply the changes

[image]

[How can I edit my Grub bootloader entries (Hide, Rename, Remove)? Preferably doing it manually, and not with a program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi)