# Uninstall Linux from Linux

Tags: boot, uninstall, mint, elementary

I searched the web for how to ***remove or uninstall Linux*** from your computer but the only information I found was how to remove it from Windows.

I've installed Linux on an old PC and I'm trying different distributions. The only OSes that I'm running on that PC are Linux. I've installed it on a fresh disk. I played with Linux Mint 32bit and 64bit. The 64bit version is the most stable one for my old PC, so I want to keep it. Also I've installed Elementary OS and my machine has a hard time supporting it. So my question is, since I'm running Linux in triple boot, how to I remove Mint 32bit and Elementary?

I'm sorry if this question was asked before. Feel free to also let me know how to not ask a question that was asked before. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Mint and Elementary are not official Ubuntu flavors. Please ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead, though you may find  existing questions here on Ask Ubuntu that answer your question.

Comment: E.g. you could try my answer here: [Uninstall Kali Linux from triple boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/930524/301745)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your operating systems are installed on different partitions. If you format partitions where your other OSes are installed and then do `sudo update-grub`, you should have them removed from your computer and only see your current OS at boot time. I recommend using `gparted` to do any partition work. You can then use these partitions for other usage.

Comment: Thanks. Again, still super new to all this. I'm Kinda like a clown. I just deleted the wrong partition. I'm reinstalling Linux as we speak. Thank for your help anyway.