# Tried to uninstall dual Linux boot (not Windows), now stuck on GNU GRUB screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I initially Installed Ubuntu 18.04. I wanted to try Ubuntu Studio to use for audio production. So, I backed up and installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04.

Then, I uninstalled Ubuntu Studio 20.04 referring [Uninstall Linux from Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996747/), re-partitioned using GParted (dragged across unallocated space), selected start up options <kbd>F2</kbd> on start-up and tried to remove Studio option at start-up.

Now I can't seem to start up Ubuntu at all. As now all I can see is GNU GRUB v2.04 screen that means nothing to me.

Comment: Thanks Terrance - appreciate you help and think it's sorted now. Advice for follow newbies based on my recent experiences: 1) it's easier to install from DVD than USB; 2) keep a DVD copy of your original install file just in case things go wrong; 3) always backup before making any other changes; 4) if things go wrong, then you can always re:install the original install, then revert to the most recent back up. Ultimately that's what fixed it for me :)

Comment: Glad you got it fixed!  =)

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy - done, although it won't let me accept it for two days

Answer (score 1):

Advice for follow newbies based on my recent experiences: 1) it's easier to install from DVD than USB; 2) keep a DVD copy of your original install file just in case things go wrong; 3) always backup before making any other changes; 4) if things go wrong, then you can always re:install the original install, then revert to the most recent back up. Ultimately that's what fixed it for me :)