# how to edit grub in terminal ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, grub2

Sorry for this I have seen it before but today i can not find it.

I simply want to set default=last OS selected.
I can't get grub customizer set it.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I edit my Grub bootloader entries (Hide, Rename, Remove)? Preferably doing it manually, and not with a program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi)

Comment: Duplicate refers to using Grub customizer, even though also there, the question was for a command line approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved                                                                                                                                           
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

After that run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Boot your desired OS.

Note that if you have a dualboot with another Linux OS, this has to be done in the system with leading GRUB2.

More info are available in the

```
info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
```